# Angular service partially available in a callback function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, angularjs-service

In my angular simple app, I have an issue with a factory that is not fully available in a callback function.

[Here is a plnckr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8HwL3NAMU1h81jwxMaWv?p=preview) with a simplified version of the application.

Here is my code :

The controller :

```
    function activate() {

        return featureService.getBoards().then(callBackOk, callBackError);

        function callBackOk(data) {
            vm.boards = data;
        };

        function callBackError(error) {
            console.log(error);
        };
    };
```

featureService :

```
function getBoards() {

        return connectionService.get(urls.featureUrl).then(callBack, callBackError);

        function callBack(response) {

            boards = {};
            actuators = [];

            response.data.forEach(function(feature){
                formatFeature(feature);
                storeFeature(feature);
            });

            return boards;
        }

        function callBackError(error) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            console.log(angular.toJson(loginService.issue));
            console.log(angular.toJson(loginService.isOk));
            console.log(angular.toJson(loginService.error));
            console.log(angular.toJson(loginService));

            loginService.issue("Unable to retrieve objects", error).then(function(){
                deferred.resolve(getBoards());
            }, function(error){
                deferred.reject(error);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
```

The console logs :

```
undefined features.services.js:71:1
undefined features.services.js:72:1
{"label":"","detail":{}} features.services.js:73:1
{"error":{"label":"","detail":{}},"graphicDefered":{}} features.services.js:74:1
Error: loginService.issue(...) is undefined
    callBackError@http://localhost:8100/app/features/features.services.js:76:17
```

And finally, the returned object from the loginService :

```
    return {
        'login'     : login,
        'logout'    : logout,
        'isOk'      : function(){return ok;},
        'issue'     : issue,
        'error'     : error,
        'graphicDefered' : graphicDefered
    };
```

I assume that the `get` method thows an exception that will be intercepted by the `callBackError` function. I suspect the lazy loader, but I have no idea about how to fix it...

Comment: I see very little angularjs code here.... Can you post all the code? also what's connectionService?

Comment: I'm sorry I can't post the entire code...   
The connectionService is actually just a wrapper around $http, I assume that the `get` trows an exception, that is caught by the callBackError function. I'm trying to create the same situation on a plnckr.

Comment: I have edited the question, you can find the plnckr that describe the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
undefined features.services.js:71:1
undefined features.services.js:72:1
```

This two undefiends are because you are calling angluar.toJson on functions. Just try console.log(loginService.issue) and it will print it.

Function issue only returns login(promise) if (detail.status === 403 || detail.status === 401) is true else it returns undefined and you can't call then on undefined.

```
    function issue(label, detail) {
        error.label = label;
        error.detail = detail;

        if (detail.status === 403 || detail.status === 401) {
            ok = false;

            return login(account.mail, account.pwd);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't understand the log this way...I didn't know about the undefiends returned when a function is parsed to json...